# how do I get data from a column from a csv that I have loaded with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I suspect this is a basic question. I have loaded a csv file with pandas. The file has literature metadata under several headings, including gender. I want to pull out all of the gender data from beneath the GENDER heading, separate male and female, and count the instances of each. Help?

Comment: `df.loc[:,'GENDER']`

Comment: tried anything?  examples?  what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: I think you should do some of the pandas tutorial [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html)

Comment: You should show a sample of your input data, expected and actual output to get some quality help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want:

```
df['GENDER'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, but...

If you have some csv, example:

```
gender,firstname,lastname,bookname
male,homer,simpson,black and white
female,marge,my family
male,bart,simpson,my first book
female,lisa,simpson,jazz in my life
female,margaret,i am baby
```

And you want to pull out all of the gender data, then try:

```
import pandas

# read source csv
# gender,firstname,lastname,bookname
df = pandas.read_csv('source.csv')

# male's data
print("data from males")
print(df.where(df['gender'] == 'male').dropna().to_string(index=False))

# female's data
print("data from females")
print(df.where(df['gender'] == 'female').dropna().to_string(index=False))

# statistic by gender
print("gender statistic")
print("males: {}".format(df['gender'].where(df['gender'] == 'male').count()))
print("females: {}".format(df['gender'].where(df['gender'] == 'female').count()))
```

↓

```
data from males
gender firstname lastname         bookname
 male     homer  simpson  black and white
 male      bart  simpson    my first book
data from females
gender firstname lastname         bookname
female      lisa  simpson  jazz in my life
gender statistic
males: 2
females: 3
```

But I'm not so sure that I understood you correctly.